# creating a data structure using another data structure in python

Tags: python, data-structures, queue, doubly-linked-list

I have a functioning doubly linked list DS that I wrote in python. Using that I want to write queue DS. The specific problem I encounter is in the below.

And I'm not sure whether my way of implementing queue from doubly linked list is correct or not. I googled but didn't find an example of this, in general how do you create a data structure using another data structure in python?

when I run

```
import import_ipynb
from Queue import *

x=Queue(2)
x.offer(3)
```

the error it gives me is `Queue.__init__() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 were given`. But I only pass one variable?

This is DoublyLinkedList

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.prev=None
        self.next=None

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Node data:{self.data} Previous Node:{self.prev} Next Node:{self.next}>"
    
class DoublyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.size=0
        self.head=None
        self.tail=None

    # add an element to the tail of the linked list
    def addL(self,data):
        new_node=Node(data)
        if self.isEmpty()==True:
            self.head=self.tail=new_node
        else:
            self.tail.next=new_node
            new_node.prev=self.tail
            self.tail=new_node
        self.size+=1
```

This is Queue

```
import import_ipynb
from DoublyLinkedList import *

class Queue:
    def __init__(firstElem=None):
        list=DoublyLinkedList()
        list.addL(firstElem)

    # add an element to back of the queue
    def offer(val):
        return list.addL(val)
```

Comment: Why don't you have a `self` parameter for your `Queue` class but you do for the rest of your classes?

Comment: The first parameter in class methods is `self`. Since you didn't use it `firstElem` is considered as `self`.

Comment: I actually had selfs but in that version it gives me `AttributeError: type object 'list' has no attribute 'addL'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forgetting to add the `self` attribute to the Queue class methods, by default it is the first argument.

Try changing the code to this:

```
class Queue:
    def __init__(self, firstElem=None):
        self.list=DoublyLinkedList()
        self.list.addL(firstElem)

    # add an element to back of the queue
    def offer(self, val):
        return self.list.addL(val)
```

Edit: Since you are trying to access the class attribute `list` from another scope inside the class, you should use it with the self before it, just so you reference the class attribute.

Comment: now it gives me `AttributeError: type object 'list' has no attribute 'addL'`

Comment: That's a different question. Just one question at a time.

Comment: @grfreitas: only your first sentence is correct.

Comment: @quamrana you are absolutely right. Deleted my comment so confusions are not made.

Comment: @fatih It should be `self.list = DoublyLinkedList()` and `return self.list.addL(val)`. And the variable shouldn't be called `list`, don't use built-ins as variables.

Comment: @Guy: You are right, but please upvote this before answering secondary questions.

Comment: @quamrana I usually don't upvote code that throws errors.

Comment: Yes, I'm with you there, but the code from the OP is so full of mistakes I'm going with one correction at a time. It fixes the quoted error.

Comment: @quamrana and sorry for the confusion I've made on this answer as well, still new in understanding the best way to answer questions :)

Comment: IMHO using `self` to call the class attributes is part of the fix to the missing `self` in the signature problem (and yes, I know the answer includes it now).

Comment: That's fine, we can agree to disagree - I just think that fixing one error at a time is a better lesson for the OP because the different mistakes result in different errors.